# update multiple rows which is having null values

Tags: sql-server

I have table with two columns which id and name.  Id contains null values and name contains some name value.  There are duplicate rows in the table.  The requirement is to update null values (id) with some value which is matching with name value. Find below table

```
Id      Name
---------------
1   abc
1   abc
1   abc
1   abc
NULL    abc
NULL    abc
NULL    abc
2   xyz
2   xyz
2   xyz
NULL    xyz
NULL    xyz
```

The above table which is having null values in the id column.  I have to update Null values with Id.  For example for abc I have to update 1 and for xyz have to update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Self Join

```
update A
    SET Id = B.id
    FROM YourTable A
        INNER JOIN YourTable B
            ON a.Name = B.Name
        WHERE A.id IS NULL
            AND b.Id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the name of the table is 'names'.
Try executing the query below.

```
update names n set n.Id = (select max(Id) from names where upper(Name) = upper(n.Name)) where n.Id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a go:

```
update MY_TABLE set id = new_id from
(
  select id [new_id], name [new_name] from MY_TABLE
  where id is not null
) A
where name = new_name
```