# Sql Server Update: Set column values by copying excel sheet data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created simple **Car Table** which has around 1500 records.

Existing Table :

```
+-------+---------+--------------+
|name   | plural                 |
|-------|------------------------|
|audi   | audis                  |
|bmw    | null                   |
|acura  | acura sports models    |
| ...   | ...                    | 
+-------+---------+--------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------+---------+--------------+
|name   | plural                 |
|-------|------------------------|
|audi   | audis                  |
|bmw    | bmws                   |
|acura  | acura sports models    |
|suzuki | suzukis                | 
+-------+---------+--------------+
```

I want to update values which has null value. 
I have Excel file which has name and plural data. however I can create list for name and plural. Is there any way to update plural in one go.

I am looking for something like not sure whether it is possible or not

```
Update car 
SET plural = LIST
WHERE name = LIST
```

Comment: And what does your expected output look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update multiple rows which is having null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162979/update-multiple-rows-which-is-having-null-values)

Comment: @inadvisableguy nops actual data in not present in the table, it is in excel file. I will make it list

Comment: In excel add a third column that contains a formula such as `="UPDATE car SET plural = '" & A1 & "' WHERE name = '" & B2 & "' AND plural IS NULL"`, then copy the result. If there are single quotes inside name and plural you must fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you will need to import that excel file into a dummy table.

Right click DB => Tasks => Import Data.... then follow prompts.

Then do a normal update statement.

```
Update c
SET plural = d.plural 
FROM car c
JOIN <DummyTableName> d ON d.name = c.name
WHERE plural IS NULL
```

As you don't want to import data.

Excel file Data :

```
+---+-------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
|   |A      | B                   | C                                 |
|---+-------|---------------------+-----------------------------------|
|  1|audi   | audis               | =CONCANATE("('"&A1&"','"&B1&"'),")|
|  2|bmw    | bmws                |     Drag to Bottom for all rows   |
|  3|acura  | acura sports models |                                   |
|  4|...    | ...                 |                                   | 
+---+-------+---------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

You may just add an extra column with this `="('"&A1&"','"&B1&"'),"` where `A1` is you `name` and `B1` is `plural`, copy that....

```
Update c
SET plural = d.plural 
FROM car c
JOIN (VALUES ('Audi', 'Audis'),
('BMW', 'BMWs')...) d(name, plural) ON d.name = c.name
WHERE plural IS NULL
```

Comment: is it possible without importing excel file?

Comment: then you will need to copy the data from the file. just do a function on excel that gets that data as `(values (name, plural), ....)` then replace that with `<DummyTableName>`

Answer (score 2):

Here, try this:

```
Update car 
SET plural = name 
WHERE plural IS NULL
```