# How to update multiple rows in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I use user_id only in a few weeks (before that I had only user_pseudo_id) ", so I want to update user_id values where it is NULL in the early part of the dataset.

I found a solution here, but it does not fit because I have more user_pseudo_id for each user_id

[update multiple rows which is having null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162979/update-multiple-rows-which-is-having-null-values/48163007#48163007)

My code:

```
UPDATE `dataset.events`
    SET user_id = b.user_id
    FROM `dataset.events` a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id, user_id 
                    FROM `dataset.events`
                    WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL) b
            ON a.user_pseudo_id = b.user_pseudo_id
     WHERE a.user_id IS NULL
```

The code is valid but it modified 0 rows and got this popup message: "UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row"

UPDATE:
My dateset now:

**user_pseudo_id____user_id**

a___________________NULL
a___________________NULL
b___________________NULL
c___________________NULL
a___________________111
b___________________111
c___________________222

What I want:

**user_pseudo_id____user_id**

a___________________111
a___________________111
b___________________111
c___________________222
a___________________111
b___________________111
c___________________222

Note, that users with a and b pseudo_ids are the same users, so they have one user_id.

Comment: Looks like you have multiple user_ids for each user_pseudo_id. In either case, which value out of the many would you choose to use in the update?  Try to find a solution where for each user_pseudo_id you have one user_id (think MIN, MAX etc).

Comment: user_pseudo_id marks an instance of the app on a given device. user_id marks the user. There are users who use the app with different devices, so it is normal if more user_pseudo_ids belongs to one user_id. Of course it is not true vice versa, a user_pseudo_id pertains to exactly one user_id. I checked it in my data, and there were a bunch of user_pseudo_id with more user_id, but I filtered them out. The problem is still the same. :-/

Comment: @Akos`- you should present simplified example of input and expected output - so we will better understand your case

Comment: so, you want to "derive" missing user_id from the rest of the table from those entries where those pairs are available - right? please confirm or clarify!

Comment: exactly, I want this! I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH map AS (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, MIN(user_id) user_id
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE NOT user_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
)
SELECT user_pseudo_id, IFNULL(t.user_ID, m.user_id)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
LEFT JOIN map m
USING(user_pseudo_id)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' user_pseudo_id, NULL user_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', '111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '111' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', '222' 
), map AS (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, MIN(user_id) user_id
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE NOT user_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
)
SELECT user_pseudo_id, IFNULL(t.user_ID, m.user_id) user_id
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
LEFT JOIN map m
USING(user_pseudo_id)
```

with result

```
Row user_pseudo_id  user_id  
1   a               111  
2   a               111  
3   b               111  
4   c               222  
5   a               111  
6   b               111  
7   c               222
```

Finally you can wrap above into UPDATE syntax as in below example

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `project.dataset.table` t
SET user_id = IFNULL(t.user_ID, map.user_id)
FROM (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, MIN(user_id) user_id
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE NOT user_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
) map
WHERE t.user_pseudo_id = map.user_pseudo_id
```

Or you can just filter only rows to update where user_id is null as in below example

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE `project.dataset.table` t
SET user_id = map.user_id
FROM (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, MIN(user_id) user_id
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE NOT user_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
) map
WHERE t.user_pseudo_id = map.user_pseudo_id
AND t.user_ID IS NULL
```